# Definite or indefinite article?

Tags: definite-article, indefinite-article

There are following rules about articles:

> - **a** - introduces a person/thing we *haven't identified before*
> - **the**- introduces someone/something that is *unique*.

What happens if I'm going to mention the **unique thing for the first time** in my conversation?

> I have ***the* microwave oven** in the kitchen.

(the only microwave oven in my kitchen)

Or:

> I have ***a* microwave oven** in the kitchen.

(I haven't mentioned it before, this is new information for my friend).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would only use *the* in such a case if you were already talking about that microwave, or the need for it is obvious from context, or if you were describing where everything is in your kitchen. Otherwise, you're not *really* talking about a specific microwave, just the one that happens to be yours.

> "Can I heat up this ready meal?"
>   "Sure, **the** microwave is in the kitchen."

(Note that it could be "there's **a** microwave in the kitchen" and be equally natural and idiomatic.)

> "Please describe your kitchen."
>   "Well, the cooker is over *here*, and the fridge is over *here*, and **the** microwave over *here*."

(Again, "there's **a** cooker over *here*" and so on is also acceptable.)

> "I heard you got some new kitchen equipment."
>   "Yeah, **the** microwave is set up in the kitchen."
>
> "Shall we watch the film?"
>   "Sure, just let me put this popcorn in **the** microwave."

(There's only one microwave you could be putting it in - the fact this is about something you're *going to do* makes a different.)

But when talking about it and what matters is that it is a microwave, you could use the indefinite article.

> "Is there some way to heat up water?"
>   "Sure, I've got **a** microwave."

(However, you could also respond in a way that talks about a specific action and it becomes *the* instead: "Sure, I can do that in **the** microwave.")

> "What appliances do you have?"
>   "Well, there's a cooker, a dishwasher, a fridge, **a** microwave..."

Sometimes, knowing when to use the definite article versus the indefinite article isn't a matter of applying straightforward rules. You just kind of have to get to know it by feel. Practice, practice, practice, as they say.

Answer (score 0):

> I have **the** microwave oven in the kitchen.

You stress in the sentence that the microwave is the "reason for talking". You do not need to speak about it before.

> I have **a** microwave oven in the kitchen.

You just mention that there are several things in your kitchen, and the microwave is one of them.