# Using 'a,' 'an,' or 'the' with 'price' and 'discount'

Tags: definite-article, indefinite-article

I am confused when to use the correct articles. For example, in an email:

> Dear Journal of Business News,
>
> I have received the information about subscribing to your journal. I have a few questions about your journal. First, you offer **a 30% discount** off **the regular price**. What is the regular price? Also, I would like to know how frequently your journal is published. Finally, would you be able to send me a sample issue before I pay for a subscription? Thank you for your help.

Why "the regular price" but not "a regular price"?

Why "a 30% discount off" but not "the 30% discount off"?

Comment: The simple answer is: Because _the regular price_ is a definite form (it is considered to be already known information in the context), while _a 30% discount_ is an indefinite form (it is not so considered). Unlike English, Vietnamese (and many other Asian languages) does not have a difference between _definite_ and _indefinite_ forms, and learning that difference is an essential part of learning basic English.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Kindly post this comment as an answer

Comment: @Bella It seems part of my comment got lost in the editing – the most important part, as it happens. Simply saying that one is definite and the other indefinite doesn't really answer the question, but the question is, in my opinion, _far_ too broad and vague, and I voted to close it on ELU (I disagree with its migration here; I think it’s off-topic here as well). It’s essentially asking “What is definiteness?”, which is much too broad for a Q&A site. (If someone disagrees with this and wants to flesh my comment out into an answer, please feel free.)

Comment: related: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/199493/18523